# React / Redux app async functions call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my React / Redux app, I have 2 functions which I want to call async. But 2nd functions seems to be called while first is in progress. I tried to add delay but didn't worked.

Here is the code

```
this.props.saveData(params);
this.props.getData();
```

So I need to call getData after saveData is done. Need help!

Comment: Check out [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: You mean you want to call them synchronously ?
Why don't you try using callbacks / promises and show us what efforts you have already put in to solve this.

Comment: @Sachin I tried this  
`setTimeout(function(){ this.props.getData(); }, 2000);` but got error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getExperts' of undefined`

Comment: That is because you will no longer have access to the context ('this') after the setTimeout. Try binding context to setTimeout using `setTimeout(function(){ this.props.getData(); }, 2000).bind(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic approach would be to [return a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from the first function call that gets resolved when the save is complete. This allows you to chain the calls:

```
this.props.saveData(params)
  .then(this.props.getData);
```

---

How exactly your `saveData` function needs to be restructured for this depends on its implementation, but the examples on the linked MDN page should give you a fairly good idea.

Comment: I tried like this as well `setTimeout(function(){
        this.props.getData();
        }, 2000);` but got error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getExperts' of undefined`